# OS X El Capitan bash shell not working in Terminal

Tags: terminal, macos, command-line, bash

I have a weird issue with my bash shell in OS X El Capitan. I was messing around with my .bashrc file today, and now when I open my terminal I see nothing out of the ordinary (no messages, just the basic bash prompt), but I cannot enter any commands. I can type, but once I press enter I just hear the bell ring and nothing happens. Some of the things I have already tried:

- Deleting .bashrc (and restarting Terminal)
- Deleting .bash_profile (and restarting Terminal)
- Making very basic .bashrc and .bash_profile files with echo statements. These statements are run and are printed to the terminal, but I still cannot enter any commands.
- Switching my shell to zsh instead, and found that it works just fine.

Any information you guys could give me would be very, very much appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT** 
This issue seems to have resolved itself. I didn't restart my computer, I just came back to it this morning and bash seems to be working just fine. Maybe a caching issue?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different, Tom. It might be best to provide your edit as an actual, proper answer so it can be selected. If the problem comes back you can always de-select the "answered" and those concerned on the evolution of the post can use the edit history link (click the time next to "edited") to see what changed and when.

Comment: Also, the **contact us** link at the bottom of each page will help you request merging of your accounts to better manage things.

Comment: Fwiw, this has happened to me before, and seemed to be triggered by an App Store update (Xcode maybe?). It was quite unnerving.